# MacBook Pro 15" won't wake up after suspending or closing the lid in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: suspend, power-management, macbook

Whenever I close the lid of my Macbook Pro 15" (2015 model) or suspend it, my screen becomes black but all my keys stay lit up. I then cannot wake up the laptop or get to the login screen. The only thing I can do is a hard shutdown by holding down the power button. How can I fix this? I have Ubuntu 15.10

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm experiencing the same thing with Ubuntu 17.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 3 11' (Intel graphics)

Comment: Same problem with v20.10 my 2011 MacBook Pro 17"

Comment: I'm also having this problem with my 2015 macbook pro 15" after updating to Ubuntu 23.04. Keys light up and the trackpad stays unlocked so you click it but the only way to get it to respond is by holding the powerbutton and restarting